# c# RPC server error when query for active username

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a function that connect to a remote computer using WMI. When I launch it with administrator privileges, the system says RPC server error.

I have the same kind of script in Powershell, it works correctly, no RPC server error (so WMI is working on the network, firewall isn't blocking it. I only found that kind of answer on the internet), and other softwares written in c# in the company are working correctly with those computers (the developer is no longer working for the company and I can't get my hand on the source code )

The same issue occurs whether I use the name of the computer or its IP adress.

```
static public string GetUsername(string computer)
    {

        string username = string.Empty;
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\computer\\root\\cimv2");
        //scope.Connect(); If I activate this line, the error occurs on this line
        string queryString = "select LogonId from win32_logonsession where logontype = 2";
        ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new SelectQuery(queryString));
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in query.Get()) //if scope.connect(); is not activated, it's blocking on this line
        {
            username = mo["LogonId"].ToString();

        }



        return username;
    }
```

I tried to run my software from the Visual Studio or directly from the .exe (using administrator). I also tried an impersonation as a workstation admin programatically, but the problem is still there.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

**EDIT** :

I already tried the solution with connectionOptions like this  :

```
options.Username = "YOUR USERNAME";
options.Password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:YOURDOMAIN";
```

and like this :

```
options.Username = "YOUR USERNAME";
options.Password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
options.Authority = "Kerberos:YOURDOMAIN";
```

and added the impersionation options

```
   options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
   options.EnablePrivileges = true;
```

Still not working.

Comment: Ive always used "                ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
                    connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                    connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;" and then used those as the second option of my managementscope parameters

Comment: Could you add a more detailed description of the errormessage the snippet is throwing? It might help narrowing down the cause.

Comment: Thank you for your proposition, but unfortunately, it doesn't work either.

Comment: unfortunately, it's in french (I don't manage the server... I would have installed visual studio in english!) But here it is : 

Une exception de type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' s'est produite dans System.Management.dll mais n'a pas été gérée dans le code utilisateur

Informations supplémentaires : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: Are you sure the `Powershell` scripts isn't using PS-remoting and executing the WMI-queries locally on the remote machine? That could explain why PS-script is working, but your `C#` code isn't.

Comment: The command I use in powershell is
`Get_Wmiobject -computername $computername ...`

I don't think it uses PS-remoting.

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of ideas then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got this... My mistake was in the line

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\computer\\root\\cimv2",options);
```

It should have been

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + computer + "\\root\\cimv2",options);
```

The variable `computer` is not recognised in a string as it is in Powershell... My bad!

Thanks to everybody who tried to help... I'll try to be more careful next time!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a username and password for the managmentscope like this?

```
static public string GetUsername(string computer)
{
    string username = string.Empty;
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    options.Username = "YOUR USERNAME";
    options.Password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
    options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:YOURDOMAIN";
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\computer\\root\\cimv2",options);
    //scope.Connect(); If I activate this line, the error occurs on this line
    string queryString = "select LogonId from win32_logonsession where logontype = 2";
    ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new SelectQuery(queryString));
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in query.Get()) //if scope.connect(); is not activated, it's blocking on this line
    {
        username = mo["LogonId"].ToString();
    }
    return username;
}
```

For more information have a look at the MSDN page for ManagementScope [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6)
And for the ConnectionOptions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7sx1w4f(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I had already tried this solution, but it doesn't work. I tried it again in case I did something wrong, but to no avail. I already read the MSDN documentation, but nothing seems to work in my case.

Comment: There are more properties of ConnectionOptions, as BugFinder mentions in his comment. My best advice is playing with these and check the permissions of the user you are using for impersonation again. And I suggest that you write it in your question that you already tried this solution, so "new" readers know not to suggest this.